# Can 27" LG washtower fit into 30.5" wide closet?

Tags: dryer, installation, washer, closet, laundry

I thought we got enough clearance as LG advises here on page 3 "allow minimum clearances of at least 1'' at the sides and 4'' behind" [https://www.lg.com/us/business/download/resources/CT00021979/WKE100H_A%20_%20WKG101H_A%20LG%20Builder%20Spec%20Sheet[20211116_004505].pdf](https://www.lg.com/us/business/download/resources/CT00021979/WKE100H_A%20_%20WKG101H_A%20LG%20Builder%20Spec%20Sheet%5B20211116_004505%5D.pdf)   Yet Delivery crew failed to install telling me on the phone It's something with my hoses hanging on the left side. I got a pict of the closet here    https://drive.google.com/file/d/1G_sOnWlxLhddO20l5GqI_ei_y_oIw9gu/view?usp=sharing If you can't tell me what's going on here? - thanks

Dims are WxDxH - 30.5 x 36x 96

Comment: Are you able to upload the photos here.

Comment: why didn't you ask them to explain it to you? ... they are the ones who refused to install it

Comment: I couldn't make out over the phone, with accent

Comment: Where is your drain—that thing at the baseboard?

Comment: the Drain location– I believe that it's inside that wall cutout where the water hoses protrude from, see the pict on Google.... if I knew how to post it here, would do